# Could not compile dependency :jiffy

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, rebar, jiffy

I'm trying to run a mix server:

```
...
Compiling c_src/decoder.c
sh: 1: exec: cc: not found
===> Hook for compile failed!

** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :jiffy, "/home/user/.mix/rebar3 bare compile --paths "/home/user/app_build/_build/prod/lib/*/ebin"" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile jiffy", update it with "mix deps.update jiffy" or clean it with "mix deps.clean jiffy"
...
```

Is there any solution for this case?

```
$ mix local.rebar
$ rm -rf deps
$ rm -rf _build
$ mix deps.get
```

Not helping :-(

*rebar 3.6.1 on Erlang/OTP 22 Erts 10.4.2*

*Elixir 1.8.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 20)*

*Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS*

Comment: Sounds like you do not have a c compiler. Try `apt-get install build-essential`.

Comment: @JustinWood Yes! Thank you!

Comment: @JustinWood Can you to post his comment as an answer? So I can to give you credit for answering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you do not have a C compiler installed. Try `$ apt-get install build-essential` to install one.